# updateEvents in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar to print events in a calendar. The problem I have is that I don't know if Fullcalendar allows you to edit the data of an event after it's been printed. I've been reading the documentation and the section updateEvent(method) but I've copied what it says there and it doesn't work at all. I don't know if I'm missing something. Please if anyone has used Fullcalendar I would thank some help.

```
  function drawControl(controls) {
            console.log(controls[0])

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                aspectRatio: 1,
                contentHeight: 500,
                scrollTime: '24:00:00',
                minTime: '01:00:00',
                maxTime: '24:00:00',
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                header:{left:"prev,next,today",
                center:"title",
                right:"month, agendaWeek, agendaDay"},



                events: allControls(controls),

                eventRender: function(event, element) {

                    var bloodLevel=event.title

                    if(bloodLevel >= 180) {
                        element.css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
                    else if(bloodLevel < 70) {
                        element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
                    }
                },
                eventClick: function(event, element) {


                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

    }
                //
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })

    }

});
```

Comment: Hola David, could you provide a piece of your code or the error you are getting? What's failing? Any error at console?

Comment: There is no error. The eventClick just doesn't work. I would like that events allow me to edit them and change their data.

Comment: In that code you are not changing the event when is clicked. You should change any of its properties before calling the updateEvent(). Just try with eventClick: function(event, element) {

event.title = "Clicked";
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

}

Comment: But the problem is that each of the events have been created through a form, so I don't know how to do that when I click on them I have the chance to change their title or their start. I don't want the titles of my events are "Clicked"

Comment: I know you don't want "clicked" on your events, it was just with testing purposes. If you have a form to create them, when you click  on the event, you should load a form to update them, using the id received from the callback in event.id. Then, in your form you can set a Save button that makes a call to updateEvent().

Comment: ok, that makes a lot of sense. I need to load the form with the event clicked, but how could I load it from JavaScript??

Comment: The way you show a new form depends a lot on your code. There are several ways of doing it. Anyway, these comments are going out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// draw your calendar
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(...);

// click something to make a change
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    var myEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    for(var i in myEvents){
        if(myEvents[i].property == myConcern) {
            myEvents[i].something = newValue;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, but I don't understand what property and something means. Could you give me a little explanation please... Thank you

Comment: 'property' and 'something' could be any property of the event object.  Here, we're basically just looping through the array of event objects and using and if statement to check a property value and determining if we need edit/change the data of the event.  Question: in your original post you want to 'edit the data of an event'.  Are you talking about editing the data of an eventObject or updating the UI view that is displayed on screen?

Comment: What I want is update the data of an event. I mean, that if I click on an event it redirects me to the form in Rails where I'm able to change the properties of my object(:level, :day, :period).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Use `loading`
2. Use `eventAfterAllRender`

Bt using `eventAfterAllRender`, which is triggered after all events have finished rendering in the fullCalendar from source.

```
eventAfterAllRender: function( view ) {
    var allevents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    var count = allevents.length;
    - - -
    - - -
}
```

Now, with the `allevents` array, do the needful.
Use a loop to get events' properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the event.backgroundColor property along with the element.css() before calling .fullCalendar('updateEvent', event).

Example:

```
if(bloodLevel >= 180) {
    element.css('background-color', 'red');
    event.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
else if(bloodLevel < 70) {
    element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
    event.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```